# error when using "push()" to add string to JSON array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to add strings to my JSON file which looks like this:

```
{
    "items": []
}
```

which is required like this:  `var items = require("../../config/item.json");`

Then I am writing it to the array like this: `items["item"].push(str);`,

which triggers an error: `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

How can I add the string "str" to the array?

After pushing it, i write it to the file like this:

```
let data = JSON.stringify(items);

fs.writeFileSync("../../config/item.json", data, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      console.log("item written successfully.");
    }
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try changing `items["item"].push(str);` to `items["items"].push(str);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `push()` method on the array, your property selector `['item']` doesn't exist it's ['items']. The json file itself is not an array, it's an object.

To push in to the array:

```js
var items = require("../../config/item.json");
items.items.push(str);
```

Or you can do `items['items'].push(str)` where `['items']` is a property selector.